# How to initialize address[] array with values

Tags: solidity

Is there any shorter way to do the following?

```
address[] memory myArray = new address[](2);
myArray[0] = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
myArray[1] = 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE;
```

Ideally something like (not working)

```
address[] memory myArray = [0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2, 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE];
```

Or at least (not working)

```
address[] memory myArray = new address[](2);
myArray[0], myArray[1] = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2, 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
address[2] memory myArray = [0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2, 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE];
```

Comment: Can't do. The function I want to call has a param defined as address[] calldata myArray with which address[2] is incompatible.

Comment: You probably wanna add that small restriction to the question, because as it stands, I've technically answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like Solidity supports this. Your first solution is the correct one:

```
address[] memory myArray = new address[](2);
myArray[0] = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
myArray[1] = 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE;
```

One option is to move this into a different file called 'Constants.sol' or similar, then do this in the constructor:

```
contract Constants {
    constructor() {
        myArray = new address[](2);
        myArray[0] = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
        myArray[1] = 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE;
    }

    address[] myArray;
}
```